# C# console application for an Auctioning system, having problem asking for the item name

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, console-application

I managed my original problem i had to add the break; but now the auction asks for the item date start price and reserve but for some reason when i add all this and then go to browse for the item it just says existing auctions : Auction
how do i make it display the name, yet again sorry for my "noobishness" but i am getting there :D your all a great help by the way thank you so much

```
{
case place_auction:
    {
        screen.DisplayMessage("Please Enter a title for your Auction Item");
        string ItemName = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        screen.DisplayMessage("Enter a start price for your item:");
        double startPrice = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        screen.DisplayMessage("Now enter your reserve price for your item:");
        double reservePrice = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        screen.DisplayMessage("Enter the closing date for your auction:");
        DateTime closeDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());

        // creating the auction
        Auction aucttion = new Auction(ItemName, startPrice, reservePrice, closeDate);

        // auction is entering auction list.
        auctionList.Add(aucttion);

        Console.WriteLine("auction is now created :)");
        Console.WriteLine("Auction details are as follows:");
        Console.WriteLine("Item name" + ItemName);
        Console.WriteLine("The Starting Price" + startPrice);
        Console.WriteLine("The Reserve Price" + reservePrice);
        Console.WriteLine("Closing date of this auction" + closeDate);
    }
case browse_auction:
    {
        if (auctionList.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Existing Auctions:");
            foreach (Auction aucttion in auctionList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Auction");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" No existing auction appearing on the system");
        }

        break;
    }
case locate_auction:
    {
        screen.DisplayMessageLine("Insert Auction ID: ");
        break;
    }
case exit:
    {
        screen.DisplayMessageLine("");
        screen.DisplayMessageLine("System Shutting Down!");
        userExit = true;
        break;
    }
default:
    {
        screen.DisplayMessageLine("");
        screen.DisplayMessageLine("Selection was not recognisable, please try again");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us the error message you're getting from this code?

Comment: the error is that Control Cannot fall through from one case label ('case1:') to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a break; statement in the end of your first case:

```
case place_auction:
    {
        /* snipped */
        Console.WriteLine("The Starting Price" + startPrice);
        Console.WriteLine("The Reserve Price" + reservePrice);
        Console.WriteLine("Closing date of this auction" + closeDate);
        break;
    }
```

For the second part of your question (assuming auction has a property called "ItemName"):

```
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Auction: {0}", auction.ItemName));
```

Comment: brilliant i got it working now thanks, but now when im browsing my items it isnt appearing, i enter the name the date the start price and reserve but im missing something that when i browse my auction it isnt showing the item

Comment: I'm assuming auctionList is a static property, or something similar. Without seeing the entire program, I'm not sure I can help you much.

Comment: yeah i understand that mate, you see this bit:
 if (auctionList.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Existing Auctions:");
            foreach (Auction aucttion in auctionList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Auction:");
            }

how would i get that to show the ItemName after it saying Auction:

Comment: @Paul Rogers:

Please read this :).

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: I have been sat trying to figure this out for 4 hours today and for like 2 weeks now, i would not ask for help unless truly stuck, thanks for the advice i will try to get it working even though i am still not sure where to add the second part into in my coding

Comment: I edited my answer to give you a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a break statement after your first case.

Comment: im completely novice to this, i dont know what this means or where to put it

Comment: break tells the control to stop when it sees a break statement. If you have multiple cases in your switch statement without a break, and if case 1 is invoked by the variable you are switching, it will begin executing at case 1, and continue executing until either it reaches the end of th switch statement or encounters a break. Hence, int he absence of a 'break' it will finish executing case i, and continue by executing case (i+1).

Comment: You have a switch statement ("switch (value) { ... } ") containing some case statements (" case (value) { ... }").  The rules for case statements are that you cannot fall through from one to the next unless there is no code in the case.  The "break;" at the end of each statement prevents execution from moving to the next case.